# Show hidden folders in sublime text? (Mac osx)

Tags: macos, sublimetext

Despite having hidden folders turned on, sublime text cannot see invisible folders in the sidebar such as a git repository. How can I fix this?

Mac OSX 10.7.5

Sublime Text 2.0.1

Comment: Why the heck does this have a vote to be closed? I want to know how to view hidden folders (something every developer in the world wants to do) using the biggest open source text editor in the world. Yeah, that's really closed, isn't it?

Comment: The close vote is most likely because this question would be a better fit on a different SE site (probably ask different or superuser).  But it does concern a programmer tool, so I don't personally think it needs to be closed here.

Comment: ST2 isn't open source

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Do you mean in the sidebar? If so, you need to modify the `folder_exclude_patterns` setting. The default value for this is `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS"]`. In your case, you would want to make it `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".hg", "CVS"]` You can access user settings by going to `Preferences -> Settings - User`. Note that this will be applied across all of your projects. If you only want it for a particular project, you can create project specific settings. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html

Comment: If you are like me, you have never changed a sublime text setting before. make sure `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".hg", "CVS"]` is in {curly braces}

Answer (score 77):

Press "Command" + "Shift" + "." (dot) to show hidden files in the Mac OSX file chooser dialog.

Comment: @djKianoosh Open Terminal and type `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`, then hit Enter and relaunch Finder to take effect.

Comment: I feel this answers the question better and it's more succint

Answer (score 7):

Sublime text makes use of file open dialog from its host computer.

In Ubuntu, just enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to toggle the setting to view hidden directories and files. The setting is persistent even after the close of the dialog.

In Windows, go to options/settings in Windows Manager, and enable "View hidden files".

I do not have Mac, it could be enabled.